# Display variable with different value

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a variable "derniere" (derniere: 200,1000,400) In the part send infos, I want to display the value at each iteration into the parameter 'response time'. How can I push value of derniere at each loop into the part 'send infos' because this part is into a another function.

```
// ******** HIDE VAR ARR ***********
for(const key in arr){
    var region = arr[key].region;
    var Value_t = arr[key].Value;
    var key_t = arr[key].cle    

    //********** HIDE CODE CONFIGURATION ************

    cw.getMetricStatistics(params2, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {       
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
        tableau = data.Datapoints[i].Average;         
        }
        derniere[key] = (parseInt(tableau));    // Send into the part send infos
    }
    });

    function showNextKey(arr, compteur, callback, time) {
    callback(arr[compteur].cle);
    compteur++;

    if(compteur < arr.length) {
        setTimeout(showNextKey, time, arr, compteur, callback, time);   }
    };
    }

    // ********** SEND INFOS ****************
    function sender(cle) {       
    const gekoq = require('gekoq');
    const push = gekoq('******'); //Geckoboard API Key
    push({
        key: cle, //Widget Key
        data: {
        "status": "up",
        "downTime": "-",
        "responseTime": derniere // /!\ Display value at each loop
        }
    }).then(response => console.log(response));
    console.log();
    }

    setTimeout(showNextKey, 2000, arr, 0, sender, 2000);
```

Result expected:

Cle: "up" "200"
Cle: "up" "1000"
Cle: "up" "400"

Comment: Maybe, it's better to use a loop for ?